# How to detect screen updates on Android?

Tags: java, android

I want to detect whenever there is update (change) on screen. For more information of what I mean, similar function could be found on Android devices by going into Settings -> Developer Options and there is a option for "Show Screen Updates". I want to detect screen updates just like that option does, but I have no idea what to do, searching on StackOverflow doesn't helps too.

Comment: Outside of a custom ROM with a modified version of Android, I suspect that this is not possible.

Comment: I presume as @CommonsWare pointed out, this isn't possible without some modification to Android. I would assume it would be a security issue to be able to check screen updates by *any* app from default APIs. In the case of apps that can "draw over screen" they require special permissions like [`SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW`](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/perms#SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW)

Comment: @CommonsWare not even with root access?

Comment: I cannot rule out root alone being sufficient. I suspect that it is insufficient.